# Finding the Lipschitz Coefficient for $f(t,y) = t\cdot \exp(-y^2)$ on $D = \{(t,y) \mid |t| \leq 1, \; |y| < \infty\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Finding the Lipschitz Coefficient for $f(t,y) = t\cdot \exp(-y^2)$ on $D = \{(t,y) \mid |t| \leq 1, \; |y| < \infty\}$.

Here is my work: Project $D$ onto the $t$-axis to obtain $[-1,1]$. This interval is closed and bounded and therefore compact by Heine-Borel. Therefore, $|t|$ attains maximum values, specifically at $t=1,-1$, We then have $$|f(t,y)|=|t||\exp(-y^2)| \leq 1\cdot |\exp(-y^2)|$$ Therefore, $$|f(t,y) - f(t,z)| \leq |\exp(-y^2)| + |\exp(-z^2)|$$ These last two terms have maximum value at $y=z=0$. So we have $$|f(t,y) - f(t,z)| \leq 2$$ But if this is indeed true then when looking at the definition of Lipschitz condition we have $|f(t,0) - f(t,0)| \leq K \cdot |0 - 0| = 0$ Which seems strange to me since $K$ is then allowed to be any constant.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Do you want a Lipschitz coefficient for $f$ asa function of two variables or with respect to $y$ ? In all cases your calculation is correct but insufficient to obtain such a constant.